# ActiveClassName with multi-tiered tabs in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React-Router doesn't recognize components for nested routes if they're different from their parent route, but the alternative keeps activeClassName in Link from working as intended.

I have a site with the following multi-tiered tab layout:

```
+---------+---------+
|  Tab 1  |  Tab 2  |
+         +---------+---------------------------+--------+--------+
|                                               | Menu 1 | Menu 2 |
+-----------------------------------------------+        +--------+
|                                                                 |
~                                                                 ~
```

My routes are defined as follows:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path"/" component={App}>
    <Route path="Tab1" component={Tab1Component}>
      <Route path="Menu1" component={Tab1Component} />
      <Route path="Menu2" component={Tab1Menu2Component} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="Tab2" component={Tab2Component} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

The tab links are defined as follows:

```
<Link to="/Tab1/Menu1" activeClassName="active" />
<Link to="/Tab2"       activeClassName="active" />
```

And the menu links are defined as follows:

```
<Link to="/Tab1/Menu1" activeClassName="active" />
<Link to="/Tab1/Menu2" activeClassName="active" />
```

When I click on "Tab 1", then "Menu 2", the active class is still applied to "Tab 1" and "Menu 2" (as they should), but the Tab1Component is still displayed.  If I move the Tab1Menu2Component route outside its parent...

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="Tab1" component={Tab1Component}>
      <Route path="Menu1" component={Tab1Component} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="Tab1/Menu2" component={Tab1Menu2Component} />
    <Route path="Tab2" component={Tab2Component} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

...then the Tab1Menu2Component content is displayed when I click on "Menu 2".  **BUT**, then you can't use the activeClassName in a manner such that "Tab 1" and "Menu 2" both get the active class... "Menu 2" steals the active class from "Tab 1".

I want to do this in a way that both Tab1 and Menu2 can simultaneously have the active class and the Tab1Menu2Component is displayed.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply return `this.props.children` from Tab1Component.

I suggest you refer the [dynamic segments example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/dynamic-segments) found in react-router repository. It pretty much deals with similar scenario

Comment: Thanks Deadfish. That certainly did the trick. I ended up changing `<Route path="Tab1" component={Tab1Component}>` to `<Route path="Tab1" component={Tab1MainComponent}>` and simply added {this.props.children} to it. Interestingly, in my first snippet of code, if I changed that to `<Route path="Tab1" handler={Tab1Component}>` that also works